# Do Rubymine support Rails view and linking of files in Rails (Engine/Module)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rubymine

Does `Rubymine` *version 6* supports *views* for [Rails::Engine](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/engines.html) that is already built?

I have a separate `Rails` project named `Kitting` as an *Engine* under `lib` folder of the main app.

Folder structure:

```
RAILS.root/lib/kitting/app/controllers/kitting/controller_name
```

Excluding the *Engine*, I'm able to render `views` in the main project.

Let me know if any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

NO Plugin Developed for RUBY MINE TO SUPPORT Existing ENGINE.
But you can open the rails engine in ruby mine as new project that would work fine.